# MSP430 ADC sampling does not work right

Tags: adc, msp430, register, software

I am trying to get the 12bit ADC of the MSP430F5529 working.
For this reason I want to read values from its internal temperature sensor every 2 seconds. The ADC setup is in the main.c file and the execution of the ADC measurement happens within a timer overflow interrupt.

My problem is that ADC12SC or "START CONVERSION", the bit responsible for starting the conversion is never set despite me setting it in the code.
But according to this flowchart when "ENABLE CONVERSION" goes up (which it does in my case) it is waiting for the sampling timer SAMPCON to go up too. Which should happen as my clock is working fine.
There is also the other alternative where I just wait for "START CONVERSION" to go up aswell but it never gets to this point.
So I think something else is not working correctly.
What is going on? I can't see my error.

Sometimes I get values from the ADC as seen in the register ADC12MEM0 but they are nonsensical so maybe ADC12SC gets set after all? Regardless I can't see ADC12SC getting set to 1 even if I put a breaking point on that line.
[image: flowchart]

Here is a picture of my registers when I run the code

[image]

Do not get fooled by the bit "Temperature sensore off" in ADC12CTL2. When it's set to 0 it is on.

[image]

And here is my code

```
  ADC12CTL0 |= ADC12SHT1_3;         //sets the amount of clock cycles to sample- and-hold for the higher memory buffers 0-7 (32 clk cycles)
  ADC12CTL0 |= ADC12SHT0_3;         //sets the amount of clock cycles to sample- and-hold for the higher memory buffers 8-15 (32 clk cycles)
  ADC12CTL0 |= ADC12ON;             //turns ADC on

  ADC12CTL1 |= ADC12SHS_0;          //ADC12SC will trigger a sample-and-hold (but ADC12SC is never set to 1 for some reason)
  ADC12CTL1 |= ADC12SHP;            //sample signal source -> sampling timer (SAMPCON signal)
  ADC12CTL1 |= ADC12SSEL_1;         //use ACLK ->32kHz

  ADC12CTL2 |= ADC12RES_2;          //set 12bit resolution

  ADC12MCTL0 |= ADC12INCH_10;       //get values from built in temperature sensor

//this part here happens when the timer overflows after 2 seconds
ADC12CTL0 |= ADC12ENC | ADC12SC;          //enable start and conversion
      while((ADC12IFG & ADC12IFG0) == 0);       // stay in this loop until bit is set thus confirming that conversion ended
      iResults = ADC12MEM0;
```

Comment: Did you get the example programs (MSP430F55xx_adc_01.c and MSP430F55xx_adc_10.c) to run?

Comment: Yes, they both work thankfully. I could try and experiment and get my code working but I think I wouldn't find out what exactly is wrong with my program.

Comment: Start with one of those, and change it so that it does what you want. If it does not work, report what exactly you have changed.

Comment: So adding these 2 lines:
REFCTL0 &= ~REFMSTR;            
ADC12CTL0 |= ADC12REFON;
Made iResults display a value. But I am still reading into what the REF module really does. But compared to the example program _adc_10.c there are some differences that I don't understand. Like for example the temp variable displays 2115 (30°C), whereas my variable iResults displays 960. Why could that be?